# Show error page in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, frameworks

Before I get into the question, I'll give you a brief introduction into what I want to do. I want to be able to show a friend;y view to users when a error happens in my Laravel project but unfortunately I don't know how to do this and was hoping some of you may be able to help me?

Hello. Today I am asking a question about Laravel. For a long time I have wanted to log EVERY single error in my laravel project. Now some of you may say that its easy, just overwrite the `handle()` method in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class.

While that's relatively easy to do, it doesn't handle EVERY single error. I have noticed it doesn't handle Query exceptions.

What I am asking is how can I handle EVERY exception. What I mainly want to do is log the error in a database table, and disable a nice view to the end user. Then if I am the one, or another member of my team that receives the error, they can easily check in the database without having to show any critical details to the end user.

I followed this tutorial but it's the same, it doesn't log every single exception.
http://blog.sarav.co/registering-custom-exception-handler-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add some code in the `App\Exceptions\Handler::render` method, for example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
        // Do something with the $exception
        // dd($exception); // analyze it
        // return a response/redirect
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In this `$exception` instance, you can find many useful information using following methods (Omit magic methods, it's a dump of `get_class_methods`):

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => "__construct"
  1 => "getSql"
  2 => "getBindings"
  3 => "__wakeup"
  4 => "getMessage"
  5 => "getCode"
  6 => "getFile"
  7 => "getLine"
  8 => "getTrace"
  9 => "getPrevious"
  10 => "getTraceAsString"
  11 => "__toString"
]
```

Also, the property `$exception->errorInfo` will give you some information as well, for example (One particular errorInfo):

```
errorInfo: array:3 [▼
    0 => "42S22"
    1 => 1054
    2 => "Unknown column 'ids' in 'field list'"
]
```

*Note*: FYI, `error` and `exception` are two different things so the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and the [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) both are for different reasons, an error handler will not catch an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to set custom exception. Or you could use [log4php](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/) they have a package for laravel I believe.

Comment: This still doesn't catch QueryException and other exceptions, am I right to put it at the top of my index.php? I haven't looked into log4php but I will now, thanks for that.

Comment: no problem, log4php should do the trick, however, it won't save to the db if that is the source of your error.

Comment: FYI, `set_error_handler` and  `set_exception_handler` are two different things.